# Facing issue while adding a node in the existing cluster(data center) in Cassandra

Tags: bigdata, cassandra-2.0

I have 2 VM's with 2 different ip address and I have install the `Cassandra (version 2.0.14)` in each.

I have mentioned the `Node A` as seed node (**192.168.93.3**) and try to add the `Node B` in the existing cluster. But i can see the below mentioned Error in while try to start the cassandra in `Node B`.

> **org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException:**

Unable to bind to address `/192.168.93.3:7000`.

Set `listen_address` in `cassandra.yaml` to an interface you can bind to.

Answer (score 0):

After change the list_address to localhost, rpc : 0.0.0.0 , endpointSnitch : RackInferringSnitch. I am able to start cassandra services in node B and it was included into the node A cluster.